# All links on Staging Ground Guidelines Help Center are broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, help-center, broken-link, staging-ground

In the Help Center article [Guidelines and best practices for reviewers on the Staging Ground](https://stackoverflow.com/help/staging-ground-reviewer-guidelines), every link except the first one is broken. The issue is that they point to something like `http://help/how-to-ask` and `http://help/on-topic`, rather than `http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask` and `http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic`. As far as I know, this is the only Help Center article with this issue.

Is this just on my end, or does everyone else experience this weird bug?

Comment: All broken for me as well. So it is not just you.

Comment: The links would work if the `http://` was removed. But if they want to use the full host name with protocol then it should be `https://`  so my guess is that `http://` gets added magically somewhere in the render pipeline

Comment: The source somehow shows `http:///help/how-to-ask` (triple slashes). I thought they mistyped the link with double slashes (e.g. `//help/how-to-ask`) instead of single slash when trying to make it protocol-relative, but that doesn't explain the explicit HTTP unless as rene's comment, the whole `http://` was explicitly added.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I independently noticed these issues before I came across this post, and have already fixed these links.

I'm guessing these were supposed to be relative links (formatted as, e.g., `/help/how-to-ask/`) rather than absolute ones (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). However, the classic editor's hyperlink button/hotkey causes `http://` to automatically be added to the start of a link – after you click "Add link" or hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> – when the URL/text you've entered doesn't start with the relevant protocol (e.g. HTTP or HTTPS), so that's probably what happened in this case.

The link formatting should now be fixed. Let me know if there are any other broken links here.

Comment: Somewhat tangentially is the "Asking" section the best place for [Guidelines and best practices for reviewers on the Staging Ground](/help/staging-ground-reviewer-guidelines)?  The guidance isn't really geared towards askers. I know "Review Queues" isn't exactly the correct category either since Staging Ground isn't considered a review queue... thoughts? (This can also be a separate question/internal question on SOT if that's better)

Comment: @HenryEcker we plan on adding a new "Staging Ground" section to be a place for these two plus more help articles to come. Asking is our "least worst" place to put them until we get around to that (there is no UI for adding sections as it is such a rare event, needs a DB migration, so take a little more organization to get it done).