# Broken link in Staging Ground email and not-rendered HTML content

Tags: bug, status-completed, email, staging-ground

I've just created my first question on Stack Overflow and got the "Welcome to the Staging Ground" email. I want to report that the two links at the end of it are broken: they both try to redirect to `http://help/what-is-staging-ground`... Which is not a valid URL.

[image]

---

Also, in the same email I've noticed it couldn't render the `"` symbol:

[image: Not-rendered symbol]

Comment: Not that we had link issues before: [All links on Staging Ground Guidelines Help Center are broken](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/423512) ...

Comment: This was previously reported by the beta test group and was marked status-planned there.

Comment: Thanks Lorenzo for the report.  As @HenryEcker commented, a fix is currently in the works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We pushed a fix this morning for the Staging Ground help content URL. We were mistakenly baking in a relative URL.

This also includes a fix to properly sanitize Markdown and other markup within the question summary presented in most Staging Ground emails.

Thanks again for the report, we really appreciate it.